# audio missing from edited video

Tags: rendering, video, audio

I edited a video and added different audio to it. After rendering the video it has no audio in it. Whenever i render the video its has totally no sound , not even its own sound, its totally mute. What am i doing wrong please help. I tried everything possible but couldn't work it out. I even tried to find encoding in my properties panel so that i will check whether none is selected in audio codec but i could not find encoding and audio codec in my properties panel. kindly help

Comment: was that the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> i could not find encoding and audio codec in my properties panel

That might be the reason. Probably you did (and could) not set any audio properties. Follow these steps:

1. Go onto the render page in properties window:

[image]

2. Scroll down to the output-tab and select a movie format as output format. **Be sure that this format supports more encoding properties.** Means: once selected directly under the output-tab a tab called "Encoding" should appear. If I can give you an advice choose H.264 as output format.

[image]

3. In encoding tab, choose your preferred Movie format. In the bottom part of the tab, choose an Audio codec different from "None". For example MP3 (if an average quality of the audio is sufficient).

[image]

Hope these steps and advices worked well :)

Greets
Jaspa